# DefaultAxesColorOrder

Tags: matlab, plot

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[1 0 0;0 0 1;1 0 1;0 0 0]);
hold('all');
semilogy(Te, iicollfreq(:,P), Te, iecollfreq(:,P), Te, incollfreq(:,P), Te,iTotcollfreq(:,P))
```

This is my matlab code for plotting 4 separate datasets on the same graph and for some reason it does not plot everything with 4 different colors. If I remove the `[0 0 0]` at the end, I get three perfectly fine, but I cannot get the fourth color to show. Does anyone know how to plot this correctly?

Comment: can you include a picture of what you get? When I execute your code with random data for the datasets, I do get four lines... It might just be that one dataset is all `NaN` and therefore isn't plotted

Comment: Ach, I found the problem.  I looked through my variables for NAN values, found that the variable Te is a matrix and I didn't specify the matrix indices in my plot function. Matlab doesn't like that apparently, so i fixed it and now it works. Thank you for telling me to check my variables. I feel dumb.

Comment: @MikeLindon: don't feel dumb, it's those small things that are easily overlooked. Only after making lots of such mistakes (e.g. trying to plot matrices over the wrong dimension), you get a hang of those common mistakes because you've made them over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

What do you get in your plot? I can't reproduce your problem.

Are you sure your plots are not overlapping or `iTotcollfreq` will not plot (e.g. it is all `Inf` or `NaN`). You could also inspect this by adding a legend or using the plot tools to see whether a graph is made.

Have you tried with random data to make sure this isn't the case?

```
t = 1:10;
f = @(t)(randn(size(t)));
set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[1 0 0;0 0 1;1 0 1;0 0 0]);
plot(t,f(t), t,f(t), t,f(t), t,f(t));
legend('show');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the following syntax to specify the colors:

```
plot(X1,Y1,LineSpec,...,Xn,Yn,LineSpec)
```

Here is example based on [@Egon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11727591/97160) code:

```
t = 1:100;
f = @(t) cumsum(randn(size(t)));
plot(t,f(t),'r',  t,f(t),'b', t,f(t),'m', t,f(t), 'k')
```

or even better:

```
h = plot(t,f(t), t,f(t), t,f(t), t,f(t));
set(h, {'Color'},num2cell([1 0 0;0 0 1;1 0 1;0 0 0],2))
legend(h, {'1','2','3','4'})
```

[image]